# Migrating btsync to new OS

Tags: ubuntu, btsync

I'm using `btsync` for sharing files.
I want to change my OS to newer version but I want to keep my `btsync` folders, keys & settings

How can I move my `bysync` to new OS?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Bitorrent sync is *weird* in a good way. It's self contained - you need to copy over the `.sync` hidden directory in the same directory you are running btsync from and things should work just fine.

That said, if you're running it from your home folder, backing up and restoring your /home or simply doing a release upgrade should be fine.